How do I write a color-changed (Style) raster file to disk
I have a GridReaderLayer where I changed the corresponding Style.
The style is an RGB Style and I have changed the ContrastEnhancement values of R, G and B.
Now I would like to save the GridReaderLayer as a (RGB byte) Tiff file on disk with new RGB values, i.e. the ContrastEnhancement I've made implemented in the R-, G- and B-band.
How do I merge the changes into the bands in the new file?

A style will only help with rendering or displaying your raster. To save it you need to make changes to the actual pixel values and then write those to disk using a tiffwriter.
There are raster processes and the jiffle language to help with your problem.
